# c++ Allocating memory for a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have this class :

```
class myClass{
    public:
        myClass(string label);
        ~myClass();
        string myget();
        void myset(string label);

        void myadd(class2 * edge);
    private:
        string label;
        vector<class2 *> myList;
};
```

I want to write a function which checks the equality of objects of type myClass :

```
 bool operator== (myClass& l,myClass& r)
{         

}
```

In order to check myList vectors of those objects, I wanted to copy l and r, sort the vectors of copies and the check if the sorted vectors of those copies are equal. But I think I failed making copies of l and r. Here is what I wrote for that :

```
myClass x = new myClass("s1");
myClass y = new myClass("s2");


x = l;
y = r;
sort(x.myList.begin(),x.myList.end());
sort(y.myList.begin(),y.myList.end())
if( x == y)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
```

This code gives this error : error: conversion from 'myClass*' to non-scalar type 'myClass' requested.

I tried making x and y pointers but it didn't work either. Can you tell me how I can fix this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I tried making x and y pointers but it didn't work"*  What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: A conversion operator should accept `const&`.

Comment: @DrewDormann 
`myClass* x = new myClass("s1");
myClass* y = new myClass("s2");`
this caused another error in other part of the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myClass x = new myClass("s1"); - here is the problem
```

Operator `new` returns a pointer. So you either store a pointer or just create your copy on the automatic storage (usually referenced as stack)

```
myClass x = myClass("s1"); - should be so (stack)
myClass *x = new myClass("s1"); - or so (heap)
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you forgetting to declare x and y as pointers?

```
myClass* x = new myClass("s1");
myClass* y = new myClass("s2");
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you only need the class to "live" for the duration of your class, you can do:

```
  myClass x("s1");
```

Or

```
  myClass x = myClass("s1");
```

If you need to have a pointer to the class, so that this function can pass it back to a calling function:

```
  myClass *x = new myClass("s1");
```